# FFmpeg enable videotoolbox on iOS

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, video-toolbox

I build FFmpeg for iOS and have enabled VideoToolbox, but when decoding video use function avcodec_decode_video2, it doesn't use VideoToolbox and very slow on iPhone.
I use the example demuxing_decoding here: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/demuxing_decoding_8c-example.html
and have try to setup VideoToolbox decoding without success.

Have anyone encountered that problem?

Comment: how did you enable videotoolbox?

Comment: I use ffmpeg buid script from: https://github.com/kewlbear/FFmpeg-iOS-build-script. It has enabled Video Toolbox in config file. But when decode video, i see that avcodec_decode_video2() only use CPU and pretty slow.